# Contour for Klein-Gordon field transition amplitude

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, propagator, klein-gordon-equation, analyticity

In calculating transition amplitude for Klein-Gordon real-scalar field, I encountered the integral,

$$ \frac{-i}{2(2\pi)^2\Delta x} \int^{\infty}_{-\infty} \,dk  \frac{ke^{ik\Delta x}}{\sqrt{k^2+m^2}} $$

I can see here the integrand has branch cuts at $ k= \pm im  $
However, later they do a change of variables $ z= -ik $ and then the integral becomes,

$$ \frac{1}{2(2\pi)^2\Delta x} \int^{\infty}_{m} \,dz  \frac{ze^{-z\Delta x}}{\sqrt{z^2-m^2}} $$

And it is said that they can wrap the contour around the upper branch cut for $ \Delta x > 0 $

[image]

I am not able to see how this transformation happens and how the contour can be wrapped around the upper branch.

Comment: By "transformation" you mean [integration by substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution), right?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/758661/2451

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a rough explanation of what they do. You start with an integral over a complex variable $K=k+iz$ along a path $\mathcal C_0$ (in the complex plan) that follow the real axis (that is a path  characterized by $z=0$ and $k$ between $-\infty$ and $+\infty$). Calling $I$ the integral without the prefactors, we thus start with
$$ I = \int_{\mathcal C_0} dK \frac{Ke^{iK\Delta x}}{\sqrt{K^2+m^2}}.$$
Now the integrand is analytic everywhere but on the cuts, so you can change the contour the way you want as long as it does not go through the cut, *and* the integral still converges.

The usual way to do this kind of integrals is to change the contour such that you just have to integrate around poles or along the cuts. But if you want to do that, you need that the contour has a contribution from $z$ at $\pm \infty$, depending if you go along the cut in the upper/lower half plan. Now you see the role of $\Delta x$: if $\Delta x>0$, $e^{iK\Delta x}$ converges/diverges if $z\to\pm\infty$, so you can't integrate along the lower cut (the integral is divergent), but you can for the upper cut. That's how you get the contour in your graph, let's call it $\mathcal C_1$.

To do the integral, you now have to parametrize $\mathcal C_1$ by two integrals : first the part along the left of the cut: $k=-\epsilon$ and $z$ going from $\infty$ to $m$; and second the part along the right of the cut: $k=\epsilon$ and $z$ going from  $m$ to $\infty$. $\epsilon$ is an infinitesimal number that you have to send to zero at some point.

With all that, you should be able to recover the result you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your answer (even though I did not ask the question). I got two questions: Are you (implicitly) using Jordan's lemma in the second parapraph? And are you talking about "principal value" in the third paragraph?

Comment: @Hunter:I guess one can use a variation of Jordan's lemma (for each quarter of circle, since there's the cut) to show that. I'm not using the principal value. $\epsilon$ here insure that the integral is not *on* the cut, but slightly on the right or on the left.

Comment: @Adam : Thanks a lot for your answer. It clarifies a lot of things here. I will try to do the math in more in detail and get back to you.

Comment: @Adam ; Following your contour $\mathcal C_1$, why exactly the integral on the first part does not cancel the integral on the second part ?

Comment: @Trimok: Good question. It's because $\sqrt{(\pm \epsilon+iz)^2+m^2}$ have opposite sign (that's why there's a cut in the complex plan !), which compensate for the opposite direction of the two parts of the integral. So all in all, the two parts give the same contribution (I'm wondering if a factor of two is not missing in the OP's second integral).

Comment: @Adam : One more question (this might be silly), how do we evaluate this integral now that we have obtained on manipulation. I see that the integrand is singular at $z = \pm m$ which is one of the limits of the integral.

Comment: @Adam, if $\Delta x >0$ then you mention that the exponential damping works, however I cannot see why the boundary terms should disappear, since $z/\sqrt{z^2+m^2}$ doesn't decrease nicely for $big |z|$.

Comment: @user35952: the singularity is of the form $1/\sqrt{z-m}$, which is integrable. Mathemtica tells me that the integral is equal to (up to the factor in front of it) $m K_1(m\Delta x)$, where $K_1$ is the 1st modified Bessel function of the second kind ( http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModifiedBesselFunctionoftheSecondKind.html ).

Comment: @YulOtani: I don't see your problem. The exponential makes the integral convergent in the limit $z\to \infty$, so we don't care that $z/\sqrt{z^2-m^2}\to 1$ is this limit...

Comment: @user35952 : Don't care about $z=-m$, because the $z$-path (just make a rotation of $- \pi/2$ from your original picture) is about the $[m,+\infty]$ branch cut of $\sqrt{m^2-z^2}$. The  $\theta$ angle prescription go from $-\pi$ (above the branch cut) to $\pi$ (below the branch cut), with zero angle for $z$ real and $z <m$, that is $\sqrt{m^2-z^2} = \sqrt{|z^2-m^2|} e^{i\theta}$. You have just to consider the global factor $K dK = (iz)(idz) = - z dz$, and you're done with your integral (with a missing $2$ factor). See [Wiki examples](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_contour_integration)

Comment: @Trimok: I think the OP's concern was about the fact that after the change of contour, the integrand $z e^{-z \Delta x}/\sqrt{(z-m)(z+m)}$ seems to be divergent at  $z=m$. Of course, this divergence is integrable, and the integral can be done (using Mathematica), as shown above.

Comment: @Trimok, Adam : Thanks. Apparently I did this integral for a different timelike separation, I am able to obtain the answer in term of Bessel functions. I think it should be valid since the integral is Lorentz invariant (to begin from 3D one).

Comment: @user35952 : I made a typo ; It is $m^2-z^2 = |z^2-m^2| e^{i\theta}$, with $\theta= -\pi$ above the cut, and $\theta= +\pi$ below the cut. So $\sqrt{m^2-z^2} = \sqrt{|z^2-m^2|} e^{i\theta/2}$

Answer (score 0):

Peskin and Shroeder's argument is just wrong.

What is not correct is their argument that one can just evaluate the integral on a contour which has been pushed up on either side of the branch cut to establish that the propagator goes like $e^{-mr}$ at large $r$.

It is a case of "right answer wrong method" as the propagator in question does indeed go like $e^{-mr}$ at large $r$ as is nicely explained in an answer to a question of my own here: [What is the missing part of the argument needed to justify the claim of (2.52) in Peskin and Schroeder's QFT textbook?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/758661/what-is-the-missing-part-of-the-argument-needed-to-justify-the-claim-of-2-52-i)
The only problem is that Peskin and Shroeder's argument is an invalid way of trying to justify the result.

I applaud user @Hunter for his/her comment on (the accepted) answer to the present question where he/she asks:

> Are you (implicitly) using Jordan's lemma in the second paragraph?

since that is a very important question to ask. The reply given by @Adam is somewhat non-commital:

> I guess one can use a variation of Jordan's lemma (for each quarter of
> circle, since there's the cut) to show that

and is not right but forgivable under the circumstances since he/she may well have thought (as I did until a few days ago) that Peskin and Schroeder's argument was a good one that could be justified by the use of a Jordan's Lemma-style argument. However, if you actually try to use it you find that Jordan's lemma does not help, for the reasons I explain in my question:  [What is the missing part of the argument needed to justify the claim of (2.52) in Peskin and Schroeder's QFT textbook?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/758661/what-is-the-missing-part-of-the-argument-needed-to-justify-the-claim-of-2-52-i)

I am therefore grateful to a user @Siam for having given a good answer ( https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/758790/362800 ) as with that answer (and the question to which it relates )we can finally get to the bottom why many people (including me prior to a week ago) have found Peskin and Schroeder's argument confusing.

One source of the confusion has been that they don't talk about the arcs that are needed to connect the ends of the real line to the ends of their displaced contour.  (That's the source of the confusion that gets most discussion on this site.)  But in my view the bigger source of ultimate confusion (which I don't see discussed elsewhere until this week on this site) is that those missing arcs can't be put back to keep Cauchy's Theorem happy without causing other (bigger) problems with Peskin and Schroeder's argument. The reason is because the relevant integral along those arcs is badly behaved!

In short: don't try to understand Peskin and Schroeder's **argument** because it's bogus, although you can believe the **answer** they give for the reason explained in the answer I accepted by @Siam to [What is the missing part of the argument needed to justify the claim of (2.52) in Peskin and Schroeder's QFT textbook?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/758661/what-is-the-missing-part-of-the-argument-needed-to-justify-the-claim-of-2-52-i)

Comment: Dear KesterKester. It is often frown upon to post nearly identical answers to similar posts. In such cases, it is often better to just flag/comment about duplicate questions, so they can get closed.

Comment: @Qmechanic : no intention tocause chaos, sorry, if you can convert this to so another  format you are welcome. there are only two instances of this similar (not identical and in both cases adapted for the paricular context) answer  and i have no plans for any more.  My only intention was to flag up that people who come to this old post should be aware of other deeper answers which contradtict/amend those given here.